# Working with JPA/Crud Repository and @Version annotation at the same time

Tags: java, database, hibernate, version

So, in my MySQL Database I work with version columns, whose parameter in the Java Classes that represent each table are annotated with the @Version.

Whenever I try to update something twice, I get an error stating this: org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction.

I noticed this happens because when I update the object, the version in the database table increments, but on my side I still have the old version with me, causing the problem when submitting my second update (let's say my version keeps up being 1 and on the Database it is 2 already). While debugging, I noticed that the save()/saveAll() method do not return the new version (are they supposed to?) that is incremented.

[image]

Here is the implementation of the persistence layer where I save this activationList

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CO_PAR_ACTIVATION_DIFFUSION_ENTITE")
public class ActivationDiffusionEntiteDb extends AbstractDatabaseObject {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6355794857690807029L;
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "TCO_ACTENT_GENERATOR", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "TCO_ACTENT_GENERATOR")
    private Long id;

    (...)

    @Version
    private Long version;
```

The object that I am saving.

TLDR: Want to know if there is a nicer way to get the updated database row versions without having to read the database again, since saveAll()/save() repository method do not return me the new versions.

Thank you.